# WPF DataGrid: set focus on a specific cell after a row validation error

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, focus

I have a WPF DataGrid with RowValidationRules. I would like to set the focus or begin editing a specific cell in case a validation fails.

For example, if the value in a cell has be lower than the value in another cell and the user does not respect this rule, I would like to automatically set the focus and begin editing the first cell.

What is the most elegant way to do this? I noticed that the ValidationResult.ErrorContent property is usually used to display an error message, but since it is of type "object", maybe I could customize it to return information about the cell that should get the focus in case of a validation error? I'm not sure how to recover and use that information in XAML though.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ValidationRule` does not inherit from `DependencyObject`, you can't define a `DependencyProperty` in your custom ValidationRule class and bind it to the proper UI element.

however I can think of a solution that helps you solve the problem:

you can still define a string property (say `TargetUINameString`) in your custom ValidationRule class and set it to the name of each UI Element like this:

```
<TextBox Name="textbox1"...
     <c:MyValidationRule TargetUINameString="textbox1"/>
...
```

add a static property (say `ActiveInstanceOfThis`) to your window from, which grants you the access to the active instance of the window class. (set it to `this` in your window's constructor)

then resolve it using FindName:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    if (value==null)
    {
        var uielement = 
            Window1.ActiveInstanceOfThis.stackPanel1.FindName(TargetUINameString)
            as TextBox;
        if(uielement!=null) uielement.Focus();
    }
}
```

it's a bit dirty but it works!